# Sonar MSBuild: Getting coverage reports on Linux

Tags: .net, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I have managed to perform static code analysis for a `.NET` core project using [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild), on a `debian:stretch` docker container.

I am now trying to produce a coverage report.

Unless I am wrong, the relevant [guidelines](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770) hint that **you cannot just use an existing report**, but rather follow a dynamic process of

- `begin`ning the analysis by pointing to the report (to be done) path
- running the actual coverage via one of the following tools:

a) Visual Studio Code Coverage

b) dotCover

c) OpenCover

- importing the report
- `end`ing the analysis initiated by `msbuild`

My question is whether it is possible to run the above process on Linux (haven't managed to do so yet or find any resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coverage reporting as also **SonarQube integration** is possible thanx to [minicover](https://github.com/lucaslorentz/minicover).

Minicover now uses mini-OpenCover to generate (and upload to a SQ server) SQ-compatible coverage reports;
The procedure that should be followed more or less, scripted:

(assuming `tools` is the folder that performs the nugget installation for minicover)

```
echo "Starting sonarqube integration"
mono /home/pathTo/SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"MyProject" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="myLoginId" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="coverage.xml"


dotnet restore
dotnet build
cd tools

export "MiniCover=dotnet minicover"

# Instrument assemblies inside 'MyTestFolder' folder to detect hits for source files inside 'MySrcFolder' folder
$MiniCover instrument --workdir ../ --assemblies MyTestFolder/**/bin/**/*.dll --sources MySrcFolder/**/*.cs 

# Reset hits count in case minicover was run for this project  
$MiniCover reset

cd ..    

dotnet test --no-build ./MyTestFolder/MyTest.csproj

cd tools    
# Uninstrument assemblies, it's important if you're going to publish or deploy build outputs
$MiniCover uninstrument --workdir ../

# Create html reports inside folder coverage-html
$MiniCover opencoverreport --workdir ../ --threshold 90

# Print opencover report
$MiniCover opencoverreport --workdir ../ --threshold 90

cd ..
echo "Ending sonarqube integration..."
mono /home/pathTo/SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="myLoginId"
```

More extensive discussion/details can be found on [this](https://github.com/lucaslorentz/minicover/pull/30) and [this](https://github.com/lucaslorentz/minicover/issues/19) threads.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get coverage out of coverlet (https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet), but so far have been unable to get sonar-scanner for msbuild to finish.  some config problem that hopefully I'll sort out soon.

The script I use is:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

api_key=$API_KEY

# Get nuget packages and then build DEBUG
dotnet restore --packages packages --configfile nuget.config /nowarn:NU1701,NU1603,NU1605 MyApp.sln

# set the version on all the projects
echo Set SDK Versions to [$apiversion]
find sdk -name "*.csproj" -print | xargs -I £ sed -ie "s/<Version>.*<\/Version>/<Version>${apiversion}<\/Version>/g" £

echo Set Implementation Versions to [$version]
find implementation -name "*.csproj" -print | xargs -I £ sed -ie "s/<Version>.*<\/Version>/<Version>${version}<\/Version>/g" £

echo Starting SONAR...
export token=$SONAR_TOKEN

dotnet /bin/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin \
    /d:sonar.login=${token}  \
    /d:sonar.host.url=https://my-sonar-server.com \
    /v:$version \
    /k:$key \
    /d:sonar.analysis.mode=preview \
    /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="$(find . -name coverage.xml | tr '\n' ',')" \
    /d:sonar.coverage.exclusions=tests/** \
    /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="$(pwd)/.output/*.trx" \
    /d:sonar.verbose=true

echo Build solution...
dotnet build --no-restore /nowarn:NU1701,NU1603,NU1605 Core.sln /clp:PerformanceSummary

# Run the tests
for testproj in $(ls tests/*.Tests -d); do 
    echo $testproj; 
    set +e
    time \
        dotnet test \
            --no-build \
            --no-restore \
            --filter "TestCategory!=Integration" \
            --logger:trx \
            -r .output/ \
            $testproj \
            /nowarn:NU1701,NU1603,NU1605 \
            /p:CollectCoverage=true \
            /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
    set -e
done

dotnet /bin/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end /d:sonar.login=$token
```

You need to reference coverlet in each of your test assemblies.